# Handling multiple http requests and discarding all the responses except for the last one

Tags: android, httprequest

I have an android app wherein i am firing http requests to fetch data from server to be displayed in mapview. I fire a request whenever the user pans,now my need is that let say the user pans 7 times (meaning 7 requests went in) i should cancel/discard the response from first 6 requests and consider the 7th response to be displayed in mapview.

I have just a vague thinking of maintaining a queue of requests as and when it comes in and post it to service 1 by 1.If a new request comes in if the request has not been already posted cancel it. If the request has already been posted and a new request came in discard its response.

What could be the best approach to handle it. Any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is: when do you decide the user is ready with panning?

If you want to create some kind of queue you need to know when to decide the user is ready panning.

After some amount of pans for example 7, you wait 2 seconds? and decide "Ok, user is done panning, lets handle the last request"?
Meaning only doing 1 request.

Or do you actually do 7 requests and only use the last response?

If you do 7 requests, why not save all responses in the same variable, effectively always using the last one.

Possibility 1 (many request, and many map drawing ):

- User pans
- send request for map information
- save response
- draw map
- and repeat above steps

Possibility 2 (Many request , lesser map drawing):

- User pans
- send request for map information
- save response
- Check timer if user is done panning?
  Yes: continue , No: repeat above
- draw map

Possibility 3 (lesser request, lesser map drawing):

- User pans
- save request
- Check timer if user is done panning?
  Yes: continue , No: repeat above
- send request for map information
- save response
- draw map

Comment: Thanks a alot timmied for ur detailed response. really appreciate it. Let me try implementing possibility 3.

Comment: Good luck! Don't forget to mark it as answer if it works out ;)

Comment: ya sure timmied have already voted +1 will mark as the answer once i am done with my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Singleton design pattern. If implemented properly, it will allow to only one thread/AsyncTask to change it's state. That way you can ensure that it will hold only the data from the last response that you handled.